# Spring JPA with Hibernate: Error during managed flush [Session/EntityManager is closed]

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, spring-orm

I am in the process of updating my application to hibernate 5.2.x and Spring 4.3.x and Spring data JPA 1.11.x

A current problem I can't figure out is related to a number of integration tests  failing with the error:

```
HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Session/EntityManager is closed]
```

(The tests are based on Arquillian/rest assured and were previously passing. I am using @Transactional annotations on the service methods as well as the repository interfaces.) 
There seems to be a problem with the managed flush initiated by Spring - as if i add a manually call to flush() at the end of the service method, the test passes.

An example of a full trace logs for hibernate + spring are available here: http://pastebin.com/LiEU7WAg

I was hoping someone could identify from the logs what is causing the entity manager to be closed causing the Hibernate error to be thrown.

**Edit one**
Below is the entity hierarchy

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"group_id",   "type"}))
public class GroupPreference extends AbstractPreference<GroupPreferenceType> {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
@Index(name = "idx_group_pref_group_id")
private Group group;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private GroupPreferenceType type;
}


@Audited
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="preference")
public abstract class AbstractPreference<T extends Enum<T> & PreferenceType> extends Identifiable {

@CollectionTable(name = "preference_entry", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "preference_id")})
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "entry_value", length = ENTRY_VALUE_LENGTH)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "entry_key")
private Map<String, String> entries = new HashMap<>();

}


@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Identifiable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2", parameters = {
@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = UUIDGenerator.UUID_GEN_STRATEGY_CLASS,
                                         value="SequentialVersionOneStrategy")
})
private String id;

}
```

The test is attempting to delete a group preference, which calls through to delete in the Spring data CrudRepository.

Comment: Please provide a short, but complete example and the relevant logs/stacktraces

Comment: Thanks @JensSchauder I attached the detailed trace logs for Spring/hibernate. I was hoping there is something obvious to someone in there them - if you search for the HHH000346. Ok, I will try and attach some examples of the (simplified) entities involved.

Comment: This is not sufficient, and it also contains tons of superfluous information. Copy your project. Throw everything away that isn't necessary to reproduce the problem. Then come back and update the question. Nobody will be able to answer your question in the form it currently is.

Comment: Ok thanks @JensSchauder, my apologies. It's difficult, there's so much unrelated code that gets in the way! I'll try again.